# using import os command via terminal gives error

Tags: python, bash

I am getting this error while trying to implement a repercussion via terminal using the import os command:

```
$ import os
$ 
$ search_list = "./emails.list"
bash: search_list: command not found
$ search_directory = "leaks"
bash: search_directory: command not found
$ 
$ def find_in_files(rootdir, search_str):
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$     for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `dirs,'
$         for file in files:
>             fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fullpath'
$             with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$                 line_num=0
$                 for line in f:
>                     line_num=+1
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `line_num=+1'
$                     if search_str in line:
>                         print(line_num, fullpath, search_str)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `line_num,'
$ 
$ 
$ email_list = open(search_list).read()
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ for email in email_list.split("\n"):
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$     find_in_files(search_directory, email)
```

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Have you tried fullpath = folder + file? Should work if folder and file is a string.

Comment: Honestly, I am a newbie in Python, hence, I don't know quite well the import os command. Do you mean filling the lines with the respective folders and files from where I need to detract the string I need? Thank you for your support!

Comment: As I can see there  is a syntax error in fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file), so try to write fullpath = folder + file instead and see if it works

Comment: ... why are you trying to write Python on a **bash** shell?

Comment: Bash shell. Thank you for your support guys!

Comment: A bash shell expects bash commands. Python code should go to a Python shell or script.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell (bash) doesn't understand python. You need to first launch  the python interpreter. this can be done in two ways depending on what you are trying to do:

```
$ python3
>>> # paste here your code
```

Or simply:

```
$ python3 -c '
> # paste here your code
'
```

Note that if the code contains the character `'` you will have to handle the escapes.

It's simpler to write the code into a file using a *text* editor and run it with:

```
$ python3 myfile.py
```

---

By the way, bash has an `import` command but that has nothing to do with what `import` does in Python:

> NAME
>          import  -  saves any visible window on an X server and outputs it as an
>          image file. You can capture a single window, the entire screen, or  any
>          rectangular portion of the screen.

So you probably have an `os` file saved that contains a screenshot.

Comment: bash doesn't have an import command. it's an external program

Comment: But can the same code line implement via Sublime text?

Comment: @Ani-hub What do you mean? You can create the text file using sublimetext. It certainly has a plugin that can run python or the shell however I don't really use it so you should search for the documentation of Sublime text.

Comment: Ok @Bakuriu, I will try now using Sublime. Thanks a lot!